# how to write this regex in php

Tags: php, regex

question seems very simple, I need to a regex to match some phrase similar like this:

"/product/12/show "

I know it may like

"/product/\d+/show"

but it failed when applied to php function preg_match, any ideas

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$your_string_to_match =  "/product/12/show";

if (preg_match('#^/product/\d+/show#', $your_string_to_match)) {
  // matched
}
```